# Choosing Azure services for .NET core application and database

Tags: azure

I have a .NET Core application that runs 24/7 in a tight loop that gets data from the Internet and logs it to SQL Server.

It's currently running on an old laptop using an old phone with a £5 data SIM -- so £5 is my budget.

I'm trying to work out if it could be moved to Azure.

An *Azure SQL Database* seems to come out at £4.56, and then I need some way to run the application. The options seem to be:

- virtual machine (hundreds of pounds),
- app service (£40.81),
- azure functions (zero -- surely this is a mistake), or
- container instance (linux) (~~£1.61 for 150,000 seconds~~ £25.84 for 2,678,400 seconds ).

But I don't understand which would work or how to choose.

Based on cost it would have to be ~~either a *container instance* or~~ an *azure functions* (it would be fine to run my application say every minute).

With a *container instance* could I put SQL Server into the container and therefore not have the *Azure SQL Database*?

Comment: If you don't use Azure SQL, you need to *buy* a SQL Server license, or use SQL Server Express. You still need to pay for storage. What does your application do though? You probably don't need a database to begin with. An Azure Function that scrapes some sites and stores the results into an Azure Blob log file may be enough. If you want to analyse the data you'd have to pay for a strong-enough Azure SQL instance to do the job - even when you don't need it

Comment: I would recommend reading up on Azure Functions pricing here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/. I think Azure Functions would be cheapest for you with 43,200 executions (1 execution / minute x 60 minutes / hour x 24 hours / day x 30 days / month). I am not sure how memory intensive your application is. However it will be a little bit more expensive than what you're currently paying though.

Comment: If you want to collect data periodically, you *don't* need a database. You'd need the database to analyse the data. You can analyse data straight from files using Azure's data analytics services. You could use Event Analytics too, to process events in real time, something you can't do with Azure SQL itself

Comment: This means that the services you need depend on the actual application, not the size of the laptop it runs on. Rewriting the application to take advantage of cloud services can result in significant cost reductions

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Express at the moment. It is a good point that SQL is not _needed_ for storage -- only for subsequent analysis.

Comment: How can I obtain a number for "GB-s" in order to estimate the cost?